# wmuSlider script dont work with custom Navigation Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to get a jquery slider called wmuSlider to work with custom Navigation Links.
This option don't appear on Demo page, but on GitHub has a script modification to allow this option:  https://github.com/adamcoulombe/wmuSlider/commit/3338599d373d61043caeb3bfbc2f644445d1bdb1#commitcomment-2249331

i'm trying to make my custom navigation links this way:

```
<a class="wmuSliderPrev custom"> Anterior </a> | <a class="wmuSliderNext custom"> Proximo </a>
```

this is the same way that the script puts on page (Seeing through Firebug).

My custon don't work, and the original works.

My custom links is the Links with Yellow Background

See my codes here: http://www.alsite.com.br/soverde/demo/

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to the person who developed the modification of the script, this is the correct method:

```
$(".wmuSlider").wmuSlider({
   navigationContainer: $("#someElementWhereverIWantOnThePage")
});
```

LINK: https://github.com/adamcoulombe/wmuSlider/commit/3338599d373d61043caeb3bfbc2f644445d1bdb1#commitcomment-2253443